# Find all documents within last n days

Tags: mongodb

My `daily` collection has documents like:

```
..
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "ED", "san" : 7046.25, "izm" : 1243.96 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "UA", "san" : 0, "izm" : 0 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "PAL", "san" : 0, "izm" : 169.9 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "PAL", "san" : 0, "izm" : 0 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "CTA_TR", "san" : 0, "izm" : 0 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-04T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "CAD", "san" : 0, "izm" : 169.9 }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-01-04T00:00:00Z"), "vid" : "INT", "san" : 0, "izm" : 169.9 }
...
```

I left off **_id** field to spare the space here.
My task is to "fetch all documents within last 15 days". As you can see I need somehow to:

1. Get 15 unique dates. The newest one should be taken as the newest document in collection (what I mean that it isn't necessary the today's date, it's just the latest one in collection based on **date** field), and the oldest.. well, maybe it's not necessary to strictly define the oldest day in query, what I need is some kind of top15 starting from the newest day, if you know what I mean. Like 15 *unique* days.
2. **db.daily.find()** all documents, that have **date** field in that range of 15 days.

**In the result, I should see all documents within 15 days starting from the newest in collection.**

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I just tested the following query against your data sample and it worked perfectly:

```
db.datecol.find(
{
    "date": 
    {
        $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
    }
}
).sort({ "date": -1 })
```

Comment: Excellent, didn't know you can create vars inside mongoDB sentences

Comment: If you choose to use the moment framework, then you can create the Date instance using: `moment().subtract(15, 'days').toDate()`

Comment: @EdwardCorrigall Thank you so much for showing this with moment.

Comment:  Using a hard-coded date (i.e. `$gte: new Date(2021,7,7)`) is _significantly_ more performant compared to the solution proposed in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Starting in `Mongo 5`, it's a nice use case for the [`$dateSubtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateSubtract/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateSubtract) operator:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-02") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-02") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-11-28") } <= older than 5 days
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $expr: {
      $gt: [
        "$date",
        { $dateSubtract: { startDate: "$$NOW", unit: "day", amount: 5 } }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-02") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-02") }
```

With `$dateSubtract`, we create the oldest date after which we keep documents, by subtracting `5` (`amount`) `"days"` (`unit`) out of the current date [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW) (`startDate`).

And you can obviously add a `$sort` stage to sort documents by date.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Please note that using $expr with $dateSubstract will lead to table scan. $expr has limitation regarding indexes uses. Documentation states: "Indexes are not used for comparisons with more than one field path operand". But the query suggested by @Xavier will transform into a filter with an $and operator. Which I suspect prevent $expr from using any index. Tested this on our own database and I can confirm Moacy Barros answer is still the best choice, especially if you need indexes for query optimisation.

Comment: `the best choice` depends on the context in which a query is used. Not all contexts depend on a big collection or even require an index. But indeed, good warning for those specific contexts.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) command to get all the unique dates. Below is the example. The "values" array has all the unique dates of the collection from which you need to retrieve the most recent 15 days on the client side

```
db.runCommand ( { distinct: 'datecol', key: 'date' } )
{
    "values" : [
       ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
       ISODate("2013-01-04T00:00:00Z")
    ],
    "stats" : {
       "n" : 2,
       "nscanned" : 2,
       "nscannedObjects" : 2,
       "timems" : 0,
       "cursor" : "BasicCursor"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You then use the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) operator with the most recent 15 dates from step 1. Below is an example that finds all documents that belong to one of the mentioned two dates.

```
db.datecol.find({
  "date":{
     "$in":[
        new ISODate("2013-01-03T00:00:00Z"), 
        new ISODate("2013-01-04T00:00:00Z")
      ]
  }
})
```