# How to get the count based on days on EST time when the timestamp is in GMT

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have something similar shown  below

[Find all documents within last n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572607/find-all-documents-within-last-n-days)

The problem is I have a timestamp in GMT but I need the counts based on EST time ...

Answer (score 0):

Time zone is irrelevant here, the document is either less than `n` days old or it's not.