# find 5 days old documents with $lt operand in MongoDB with Jongo - query returns empty result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jongo

Data in MongoDB collection has format

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a1bfc103c8851a98dba3b2"), "createdOn": NumberLong("1470218177561"), "name": "Raja", "description": "Employee Raja" }
```

Mongo DB Query and Results

```
> new Date(1470218177561);
 ISODate("2016-08-03T09:56:17.561Z")

> new Date(1888888888888);
 ISODate("2029-11-09T03:21:28.888Z")

> db.employee.find("{createdOn: { $lt: new Date(NumberLong(1888888888888)) }}");
```

The last query returns no result without any errors, so I can't determine what is wrong with my query.

Basically, want to find the records for the last 5 days with `$lt operator  in Jongo. Tried the next query, but it also not working

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
Date dateBefore = cal.getTime();
collection.find("{createdOn: {$gte : #}}", dateBefore).as(type);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove double quotes: `db.employee.find({createdOn: {$lt: new Date(NumberLong(1888888888888))}});`

Comment: Still mongo shell returns empty records even after removing the double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing

`NumberLong("1470218177561")` vs `new Date(NumberLong(1888888888888))`

instead of comparing

`NumberLong("1470218177561")` vs `NumberLong(1888888888888)`

In your particular case the query will be

```
db.employee.find( { createdOn: { $lt: NumberLong(1888888888888) } } );
```

---

To find documents that are 5 days old you can [look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572607/find-all-documents-within-last-n-days).

To get current date in milliseconds

```
> new Date(new Date()).getTime()
1470232681000
```

To find 5 days old documents use `$gt` operator on the date that is 5 days before now

```
> new Date(new Date()).getTime() - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
1469800939000
```

So the query will be

```
db.employee.find( { createdOn: { $gt: new Date(new Date()).getTime() - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } } );
```

---

To get the same result with Jongo

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
employees.find("{ createdOn: { $gt:  # } }", cal.getTimeInMillis() - 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

The problem with your query for Jongo was the same. You were trying to find by `Date` type, but date field of documents in your collection is `NumberLong`, that is millisecond long representation of `Date` type.

You cannot compare 2 different types with operators like `$gt`.

Comment: Basically i want to fetch the records less than the given date. Please let me know the query for the above

Comment: @Kathire Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. posting another question related to mongo api query. please kindly help if possible

Comment: Hi,

Sample Collection: Employee

Record: 

       {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57a1bfc103c8851a98dba3b2"),
        "createdOn" : "1470218177561",
        "name" : "Raja",
        "description" : "Employee Raja"
       }

Below Query is not working
     
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
    Date dateBefore = cal.getTime();
    collection.find("{createdOn: {$gte : #}}", dateBefore).as(type);

Basically i am trying to find records for the last 5 days.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, but it is not allowing me to create till 90 minutes. so could you please help me or can u post for me? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kathire Updated the answer

Comment: This is perfectly working in mongo shell where as not working via MongoCollection API via jongo. throws cannot parse exception on new - { createdOn: { $gt: new Date(new Date()).getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } }

Comment: `code` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse query: { createdOn: { $gt: 
new Date(new Date()).getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } }

at org.jongo.query.BsonQueryFactory.createQuery(BsonQueryFactory.java:162)
at org.jongo.Find.<init>(Find.java:47)
at org.jongo.MongoCollection.find(MongoCollection.java:88)
at org.jongo.MongoCollection.find(MongoCollection.java:84) `code`

Comment: @Kathire Updated the answer. Next time try to specify all aspects of your problem and the environment where you want to handle it (f.e that you need the result in Jongo, not just in mongo Shell).